# Android: How can I set buttons on google mapview as not transparent

Tags: android

So far I have a google mapview and I want two buttons on the mapview displayed. But when I add them like this

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="..."
    android:clickable="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/etageplus"
    android:
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="+" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/etageminus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etageplus"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etageplus"
    android:text="-" />
```

...they are transparent and I don't want them transparent. Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the background color or drawable?  The first octet of the color is transparency, FF being fully opaque